# Cannot use javascript variable as property in Grails

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

This is a javascript/jQuery function . Here i am accessing grails session variable from javascript

```
 function changeContactPersonDetails(value){
    alert(value)
    //alert(typeof(value))
    $("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name[" + value + "]}");
 }
```

here i want to use value of a variable "`value`" as index . but it gives error

```
 Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Exception evaluating property ' + value + ' for java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:  + value +  for class: java.lang.String
    at E__Workspace_opaltpm_grails_app_views_trainingOrder__billingDetailsTemplate_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(E__Workspace_opaltpm_grails_app_views_trainingOrder__billingDetailsTemplate_gsp:15)
```

Comment: dude, i am not sure about grails, but in jquery part you have enclosed the ${session.traineeDetais.name[" + value + "]} with double quotes, may be this is causing the problem, Ex: if you want to use other language in jquery like php, it will be like $("#billingPersonName").val(<?php echo session.traineeDetais.name[" + value +"] ?>);

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing server- and clientside code.

The variable `value` is the parameter of your (clientside) jquery function.

The following code `${session.traineeDetais.name[" + value + "]}` is executed by grails (serverside), where the variable `value` is unknown.

You have to pass the array to your client, that you could access it within your jquery functions.

Use `JSON` to pass the data like this:

```
var dataFromServer =  ${session.traineeDetais.name as grails.converters.JSON}

function changeContactPersonDetails(value){
    alert(value)
    $("#billingPersonName").val(dataFromServer[value]);
}
```

*A much cleaner way would be to compute/convert your array within the controller and pass it to the view ...*

Comment: getting this error:
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error evaluating expression [session.traineeDetais.name as grails.converters.JSON] on line [7]: Cannot cast object '[Ljava.lang.String;@1c42b98' with class '[Ljava.lang.String;' to class 'grails.converters.JSON' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: grails.converters.J
SON(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Instead of creating the dataFromServer JSON within your view, you should create that JSON Array within your action and pass it as a variable within your model - just for sepration of logic and layout ...

Comment: It makes no sense to edit your comments and replace it with another question... I don't know the type of content you are saving within your session. I have assumed that `session.traineeDetais.name` is an array. It looks like it is just a string instead of an array. Check your variables first.

Comment: The given code is just an example. You have to figure out how to adapt to your specific use case or give more details.